# Creating a dataframe from data stored in a text file in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have information from a mapreduce job that is stored in text file and takes the following form:

```
Book Title:Token   Count
Book1:Word1   5
Book2:Word1   6
Book1:Word2   2
```

I am trying to convert this into a dataframe that looks like the following, which would list all of the unique words in the first column, and then list the number of times each word occurs in each respective document in the adjacent columns:

[image: Table]

So far, I have the following code to separate the "Book Title" "Token" and "Count" from each line of the text file

```
for line in unigrams:
    token, count = line.strip().split("\t")
    document = token.split(":")[0]
    word = token.split(":")[1]
    x[i] = {'Document': document, 'Word' : word.strip(), 'Count' : count.strip()}
```

The dictionary is set outside the for loop and i is incremented at the bottom. I then convert the dictionary 'x' to a dataframe with the following line

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient="index")
```

Any guidance on how I should modify the above code to achieve the result mentioned would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Did your code work or give any errors? It will be useful if we have a Minimal Working example to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas offers handy pivot tables for your use case.

```
import pandas as pd

x = [{"Document": "Doc 1", "Word": "Word 1", "Count": 3},
    {"Document": "Doc 2", "Word": "Word 2", "Count": 1},
    {"Document": "Doc 3", "Word": "Word 3", "Count": 2},
    {"Document": "Doc 3", "Word": "Word 1", "Count": 6},
    {"Document": "Doc 1", "Word": "Word 2", "Count": 1},
    {"Document": "Doc 2", "Word": "Word 3", "Count": 7}]

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df = df.groupby(["Word", "Document"]).sum().reset_index()
df.pivot(index="Word", columns="Document")
```

This has the added benefit of using your Document and Word values as indices for fast access.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I've marked this as the answer.

Comment: Great glad this helped!